# Pass argument to python script running in a docker container

Tags: python, laravel, docker, dockerfile

Suppose the following setup:

- Website written in php / laravel
- User uploads a file (either text / doc / pdf)
- We have a docker container which contains a python script for converting text into a numpy array.

I want to take this uploaded data and pass it to the python script.

I can't find anything which explains how to pass dynamically generated inputs into a container.

Can this be done by executing a shell script from inside the laravel app which contains the uploaded file as a variable specified in the dockerfile's ENTRYPOINT?

Are there any other ways of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... a python script for ...

Just run it; don't package it into a Docker container.  That's doubly true if its inputs and outputs are both local files, and it expects to do its thing and exit promptly: the filesystem isolation Docker provides works against you here.

---

This is, of course, technically possible.  Depending on how exactly the support program container is set up, the "command" at the end of `docker run` will be visible to the Python script in `sys.argv`, like any other command-line options.  You can use a `docker run -v` option to publish parts of the host's filesystem into the container.  So you might be able to run something like

```sh
docker run --rm -v $PWD/files:/data \
  converter_image \
  python convert.py /data/in.txt /data/out.pkl
```

where all of the `/data` paths are in the container's private filesystem space.

There are two big caveats:

1. The host paths in the `docker run -v` option are paths *specifically on the physical host*.  If your HTTP service is also running in a container you need to know some *host-system* path you can write to that's also visible in your container filesystem.
2. Running any `docker` command at all effectively requires root privileges.  If any of the filenames or paths involved are dynamic, **shell injection attacks can compromise your system**.  Be very careful with how you run this from a network-accessible script.

Comment: Thanks David - after reading your answer and evaluating what I need to do, I think you're right to say 'just run it'. I need the function to be event driven (i.e when a user uploads a file, do some processing) so I think the best way of doing this is to have it run in AWS Lambda rather than in Docker and pass http requests to it.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend using tcp/ip for such purposes. By the way, in this case you benefit from:

- You can detect whether your python service is online
- You can move python container to another machine

Implementation is really simple. You can choose any framework, but for me suitable is `Twisted`, and implement your python script as follows:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, Protocol
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver

class DataProcessor(LineReceiver):
  def lineReceived(self, line):
    # line contains your data
    pass

Factory factory = Factory()
factory.protocol = DataProcessor
reactor.listenTCP(8080, factory)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @grapes - I haven't tested this but appreciate you contributing. I'm just going to avoid using Docker for the client and instead have the python script run in AWS Lambda / Cloud Functions.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to upload the files to a directory to which the Docker container has access to and then poll the directory for new files using the Python script. You can access local directories from Docker containers using ["bind mounts"](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/). Google something like "How to share data between a Docker container and host system" to read more about bind mount and sharing volumes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Delena - I haven't tested this but appreciate you contributing. I'm just going to avoid using Docker for the client and instead have the python script run in AWS Lambda / Cloud Functions.